# Binding not working in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Below is my `ParamModel` class which is inherited from `DependencyObject`

```
public class ParamsModel : DependencyObject
{
    public object MyProperty
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(ParamsModel), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ParamsModel()
    {

    }

}
```

I have referred this class in my `XAML` like below

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.MyName,ElementName=pageRoot}" />
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"
         Width="500"
         Height="500">
    <local:ParamsModel MyProperty="{Binding DataContext.MyName,ElementName=pageRoot}" />
</ListBox>
```

I have put breakpoint at `MyProperty` setter which is not hitting at runtime, but the same class `Constructor` is hitting. Could anyone please help me on this

Answer (score 1):

It is because the binding mechanism don't call the `CLR` property of dependency property. It calls `GetValue/SetValue` directly.

Comment: I have bind to a DataContext property which is not at all setting

Comment: MyProperty of local:ParamsModel not setting the value which i have binded in the XAML

Comment: How do you know it is not being set? As @HamletHakobyan mentioned, just by putting a breakpoint in the setter, you won't see it being executed but that doesn't mean it is not being set.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to bind to a DependencyObject view model in a Store App and it just wouldn't work unless I put the PropertyMetaData parameter to null instead of new PropertyMetadata(null).